# Query joining three tables and getting count for one field not returning zero values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, count

I have three tables: Dept, DocType, Documents. I need a list of all the DocTypes with their corresponding Dept., and the count of Documents for each DocType per Dept. There are fields in each table to link them properly. My problem is I'm getting the counts correctly, but the DocTypes which don't have any documents are not getting listed in results as zero.

I want:

```
Accounting    Faxes   3
Accounting    Memos   0
Accounting    Misc    10
```

But I'm getting:

```
Accounting    Faxes   3
Accounting    Misc    10
```

Here's my query. Any ideas?

```
select DE.DeptName, DT.DocTypeID, COUNT(Docs.DocNumber)
from DocTypes as DT
left join Documents as Docs on Docs.DocTypeID = DT.DocTypeID
left join Dept as DE on DE.DeptID = Docs.DeptID
group by DT.DocTypeID, DE.DeptName
order by DE.DeptName, DT.DocTypeID
```

Dept table has:
DeptID, DeptName

DocType table has:
DeptID, DocTypeID

Docs table has:
DeptID, DocTypeID, DocNumber

Any ideas?

Comment: Sample table data producing the expected result would help.

Comment: Is there a table that lists all possible doc types?  Which table.

Comment: Your `join` is backwards I think.  You should start with the `dept` table, then `outer join` to the `doctype` table and then to the `documents` table...

Comment: @sgeddes -- that won't work -- if that worked then the example he gave would work.  doctype does not contain all doctypes -- so even tho the name sounds like it doctypes is not a list of all document types

Comment: @Hogan I think we need sample data to know for sure.  I was guessing the original query returned another `null` row without a department name.  Might need some sort of `cartesian product` if there isn't any relationship though.

Comment: Expected result is a list of all depts., with all doctypes and the count of docs:
Accounting    Faxes   3
Accounting    Misc    10

Comment: The DocTypes table contains all the doctypes and the Dept table contains all the Depts. The Docs table contains Dept,DocType, and DocNumber

Comment: @JanniceTorres -- what table is the list of depts in?

Comment: in the above you list doctypes as having `DeptID, DocTypeID` is that a typo?  because that is a joining table not a lookup table.

Comment: @Hogan - The DocTypes table contains all the doctypes, so I put it in the FROM clause.

Comment: @Hogan, the Dept table contains all Depts.

Comment: @Hogan - The DocTypes table is one-to-many to Depts. It contains the DocTypeID and the DeptID to which it belongs.

Comment: Exactly so there is no Memos there because it does not exist in any dept you need a table with a list of all deps.

Comment: Looks like you could just change your LEFT joins to FULL OUTERs

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query

```
SELECT DE.deptname, 
       DT.doctypeid, 
       Count(Docs.docnumber) 
FROM   dept AS DE 
       LEFT JOIN documents AS Docs 
              ON DE.deptid = Docs.deptid 
       LEFT JOIN doctypes AS DT 
              ON Docs.doctypeid = DT.doctypeid 
GROUP  BY DT.doctypeid, 
          DE.deptname 
ORDER  BY DE.deptname, 
          DT.doctypeid
```

Comment: This query returns the same results my query returns, correct counts for DocTypes existing in the Docs table, but I need all DocTypes from the DocTypes table, so I also get the zeros.

Comment: Can you provide sample data

Comment: Dept Table Data:

DeptID  DeptName
1           Accounting
2           Billing

Answer (score 0):

Switch the `joins`. The reason why you are not getting doctypes is, that you start your query with the doctypes, which can be null - so there is nothing to "join". Start your query with the data which is always present i.e. `dept`.
Try this one:

```
select 
    DE.DeptName, 
    DT.DocTypeID, 
    COUNT(Docs.DocNumber)
from 
    Dept as DE
left join 
    Documents as Docs on DE.DeptID = Docs.DeptID
left join 
    DocTypes as DT on Docs.DocTypeID = DT.DocTypeID
group by 
    DT.DocTypeID, 
    DE.DeptName
order by 
    DE.DeptName, 
    DT.DocTypeID
```

Comment: DocTypes table is the list of all DocTypes, even if there are no documents for it.

Comment: This query is the same as Anson's above. I get correct counts, but no zero values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which RDBMS you're using so the answer will vary, but taking Oracle as an example you could use NVL(COUNT(Docs.DocNumber), 0). Basically if COUNT(Docs.DocNumber) returns NULL it will return 0 instead. There will be something similar in whichever RDBMS you're using.

Comment: MS SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: So a quick Google suggests the SQL Server equivalent would be ISNULL(COUNT(Docs.DocNumber). Give it a try :-). COALESCE() is also an option.

Comment: Ok, typo in my last comment. Should be ISNULL(COUNT(Docs.DocNumber), 0)

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following query:

```
select DE.DeptName, DT.DocTypeID, COUNT(Docs.DocNumber)
  from Dept as DE
  left join DocTypes as DT on DT.DeptID = DE.DeptID
  left join Documents as Docs on (Docs.DeptID = DE.DeptID and Docs.DocTypeID = DT.DocTypeID)
 group by DT.DocTypeID, DE.DeptName
 order by DE.DeptName, DT.DocTypeID
```

The important thing is for the `DocTypes` table to be joined before `Documents` table if you want it in your results set. If `Documents` table is joined first and there is no entry for some doc-type, there would be nothing to join in the first place.

Other than that, I'd also added `Docs.DeptID = DE.DeptID` to your join, as you want to count the documents only per one `DeptId`.
It is recommended to join tables using all of the common columns, which are these, as you have pointed out:

> Dept table has: DeptID, DeptName
>
> DocType table has: DeptID, DocTypeID
>
> Docs table has: DeptID, DocTypeID, DocNumber

Without it, you'd be multiplying your results the way you wrote it in the question. Either way, the sum of counted values should be exactly the same as the number of rows in Docs table itself - so that is the way to check if you are (multiplying your results).

I hope I helped!

Comment: This query is not returning correct counts.  I see zeros where there should by a positive number of docs.

Comment: @JanniceTorres Can you please do me a favor and check your data visually for those examples. The reason for my request is that I strongly believe that it's the other way around: that your code have not joined your `DocType` table with your `Dept` table and you're multiplying your results. Either way, the sum of counted values should be exactly the same as the number of rows in `Docs` table itself. If your sum is more than that number of rows than I'm right. If my count is less than that number of rows than I'm mistaken. Please contact me with this info.

Comment: I'm going through all the comments. Thank you for understanding. It takes time.  I'm connect again asap. Can't find how to edit my question to provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

First you need the cross product of all document types and all departments

> The reason this works is the cross product here gives us a list of all possible things to count.  When we select from it it we will know if there is something we want to count that is not there.  In SQL you have to think in sets... this gives us the set of things to count.

So we do something like the following (I'm still not 100% what table has what data  -- In this case I'm guessing that Documents table will have all doc types and Dept table will have all departments.)

```
 SELECT DocTypeID, DeptID
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DocTypeID FROM Documents)
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DeptID FROM Dept)
```

We then use this to group by and join to the rest of the data

```
 select DE.DeptName, docs.DocTypeID, COUNT(Docs.DocNumber)
 FORM (
   SELECT DocTypeID, DeptID
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DocTypeID FROM Documents)
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DeptID FROM Dept)   
 ) AS base 
 left join Documents as Docs on Docs.DocTypeID = base.DocTypeID
 left join Dept as DE on DE.DeptID = base.DeptID
 group by docs.DocTypeID, DE.DeptID
 order by DE.DeptID, docs.DocTypeID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
SELECT 
    DE.DeptName, DT.DocTypeID, ISNULL(COUNT(Docs.DocNumber), 0)
FROM
    DocTypes AS DT
        LEFT JOIN
    Documents AS Docs ON Docs.DocTypeID = DT.DocTypeID
        LEFT JOIN
    Dept AS DE ON DE.DeptID = Docs.DeptID
GROUP BY DT.DocTypeID , DE.DeptName
ORDER BY DE.DeptName , DT.DocTypeID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is FYI, we revised our requirements and will no longer need the count to include zeros.  I truly appreciate all your suggestions and have saved the thread to continue working on it when time allows.